# Understanding Loops in Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Trying to understand this and how it works. Basically the goal was to have the user input the password to "gain access". This was the code but I'm trying to understand it exactly.

Couple questions really:
1. Why is the output being stated as no access first why not a else if does that not work?
2. I'm very confused about how the whole Loop function works if someone could explain the i = 0; userPassword.length > i ; i++

```
function btnCheckCode_onclick()
{
    // assign textbox elements to variables for easier access
    var userInputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtCode");
    var outputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtOutput");

    var userInput = userInputTextbox.value
    var userPassword = ["Admin", "Secret", "Letmein", "abc123", "qwerty"];
    var output = "Sorry, No Access";

    for(i = 0; userPassword.length > i ; i++ )
    {
        if(userPassword[i] == userInput) 
        {
            output = "Welcome Privileged User";
        }

    }

    userInputTextbox.value = userInput
    outputTextbox.value = output
}
```

Comment: I think `userPassword.length > i` should be `i < userPassword.length `, clearer that way.

Comment: @TeaCode I've tried < i and it didn't work > i and it works so no idea lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It loops through the array of password to see if there's a match with the given password.

- It uses I as a counter, and initializes it to 0.
- The next part is evaluated every time the loop runs to check whether the loop should continue or not. In this case, it only continues as long as i is smaller than the password length.
- The i++ part increases the loop counter every time the loop is ran.

Now, having said that, please don't use this code anywhere. Checking for a password is not something that you should do in the client. Everybody can see this code, and it's very simple to bypass this check.

Comment: Why do you say need to use a loop and not a if else if statement?

Comment: @Mibby: What I mean is that this code is not safe to use. Just suck up the advice that you get here, and delete the code.

Comment: This code isn't being used for anything important it's learning material. Also no need to be hostile I'm sorry if you're a wiz and I'm not hence me asking the questions.

Comment: I didn't notice that I was being hostile. If you look up a few lines up here, you see that while everybody downvotes your question, I'm actually trying to help you by explaining things.

Comment: I'm used to being downvoted comes with being on here I noticed and you were a tad earlier but yes you definitely helped me understand it more was just wondering why not use if and else if does it not work or is it just longer and not a norm?

Comment: I don't know how you'd use if statements. You could check each item one-by-one and use if statements for each. Like if(userPassword[0]=='xxx'), etc. But that would be harder to maintain, especially when your list of possible passwords grows longer.

Answer (score 1):

the value of `output` is set before the loop:

```
var output = "Sorry, No Access";
```

and only changed if the condition inside the loop

```
userPassword[i] == userInput
```

evaluates to `true`.  So the answer to your first question is that you are setting that specific initial value yourself.

Regarding your second question, the parameters of the loop construct:

```
i = 0; i < userPassword.length; i++
```

are defined as:

```
variable = initial value; variable < limit; increment variable after iteration
```

in other words, you declare the variable `i` and set it to `0`; you tell the interpreter to iterate as long as the value of `i` is less than the value of the limit or specifically the length of the `userPassword` array; and you add `1` to the value of `i` after each iteration.

inside the first loop iteration `i=0` and after it, `i=1`. Since the length of `userPassword` is `5`, the loop will continue. After the 2nd iteration, `i == 2`, and the loop continues until `i == 5`. Since the 5 indices of `userPassword` are identified as `[0,1,2,3,4]` this works out quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The for-loop is iterating through the userPassword array. The length of the array is 5 right now, but it could change in the future. Using the array's length as part of the conditional means you don't have to change the loop if you make the array longer or shorter.

For the loop, you need a variable that is going to act as an iterator: `i`. Items in an array are indexed from 0 to 1 less than the array's total length. You want the value of the iterator `i` to start at the beginning of the array, 0, and go all the way to the end.

In your case the end of the loop is also the end of the array, which is defined by your conditional: `userPassword.length > i`

When you have something like `userPassword[i]`  it represents the value the array holds at this index--the `i` will be replaced by an integer during the loop. In your loop you're iterating index by index and checking the value in the array at that index against the one the user entered until the iterator reaches the limit defined by your conditional.

As for your first question, it's common to initialize every variable at the beginning of the function. `output` could have been anything before your function runs, but by initializing `output` with a message you don't run the risk of trying to handle an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

This for instruction is a loop that goes through the list of possible user password and compares it with the one entered, if there is a match it changes the output:

```js
// assign textbox elements to variables for easier access
var checkPassword = function () {
    var userInputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtCode");
    var outputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtOutput");

    var userInput = userInputTextbox.value;
    var userPassword = ["Admin", "Secret", "Letmein", "abc123", "qwerty"];
    var output = "Sorry, No Access";

    for(i = 0; i < userPassword.length; i++ )
    {
        if(userPassword[i] == userInput) 
        {
            output = "Welcome Privileged User";
        }

    }

 
    outputTextbox.innerHTML = output;
  }
```

```html
<input id="txtCode" value="Admin">
<div id="txtOutput"> </div>

<button onclick="checkPassword()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Because if the user does not type any of this strings "Admin", "Secret", "Letmein", "abc123", "qwerty" the the output don't need to be set to "Sorry, No Access" afterwards because it is the default.
2. i = 0: is the start value of i, userPassword.length > i
   userPassword.length is the number of elements in the array => 5
   i++ means after every iteration set i to i + 1

The loop just checks if the user input matches one of the strings in the userPassword array if it does match output will be set to "Welcome Privileged User".
The problem is that if the user types "Admin" the loop checks the other four values too.

```
userPassword.some(password => {
  if(password == userInput){
     output = "Welcome Privileged User";
  }
  return password == userInput;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(userPassword[i] == userInput) {
   output = "Welcome Privileged User";
} else {
   output = "Sorry, No Access";
}
```

I added *else* and now lets check variants:

```
0 iteration: true -> output = "Welcome Privileged User";
1 iteration: false -> output = "Sorry, No Access";
2 iteration: false -> output = "Sorry, No Access";
3 iteration: false -> output = "Sorry, No Access";
4 iteration: false -> output = "Sorry, No Access";
```

So, *output = "Sorry, No Access"* (but we have true iteration). It's because *else* statement rewrite variable *output* if condition is `false`.

When we define *output* before *for* loop, *output* can change the value only when condition `if(userPassword[i] == userInput)`returns `true`. So, this variant is correct.

About **for loop**. The *for* loop is often the tool you will use when you want to create a loop.

The *for* loop has the following syntax:

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
    code block to be executed
}
```

In your case:

```
 for(i = 0; userPassword.length > i ; i++ ) {
        code block to be executed
    }
```

**Statement 1** sets a variable before the loop starts (var i = 0).

**Statement 2** defines the condition for the loop to run (userPassword.length must be greater than i).

**Statement 3** increases a value (i++) each time the code block in the loop has been executed.

Inside *for* loop you have *if* statement.

```
   if(userPassword[i] == userInput) {
      output = "Welcome Privileged User";
    }
```

Each element of array `userPassword = ["Admin", "Secret", "Letmein", "abc123", "qwerty"]` compare with *userInput*:

```
if(userPassword[0] == userInput) => if("Admin" == userInput)
if(userPassword[1] == userInput) => if("Secret" == userInput)
if(userPassword[2] == userInput) => if("Letmein" == userInput)
if(userPassword[3] == userInput) => if("abc123" == userInput)
if(userPassword[4] == userInput) => if("qwerty" == userInput)
```

If one of conditions returns `true` then we set *"Welcome Privileged User"* for variable *output*. If all conditions are `false` we keep defined value *"Sorry, No Access"*.

One remark:

```
 for(i = 0; i < userPassword.length; i++)
```

This syntax is more useful and easier for understanding.

Some examples you can find here: [JavaScript For Loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)